# RStudio Install Packages and Package Updates both download then fail with cannot open file

Tags: r, rstudio, updates, install.packages

Running happily with R 3.4 and RStudio 1.0.143 under Win10 this problem occured bringing project development to a halt.  Downloads each occur and are unzipped and then the a presumably first file in the first item gets:

```
Error in install.packages : cannot open file 'C:/Users/Admin/Documents/R/
win-library/3.4/file30504386b80/rJava/javadoc/resources/background.gif': 
Permission denied
```

and the prompt returns.

Updating to R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30), RStudio Version 1.0.153 was to no avail.  Using the OS to remolve all R versions and trying again with 3.4.1 did not work. Removing R again and deleting the R directory to refresh the library did not work.  My virius software like to tell how helpful it has been and has not, so that issue seems unlikely.

Giving the user full control of the R library did not help.

could package-updates be a tag like install-updates?

Answer (score 0):

It looks there is a problem between Java and rJava.

You should try reinstalling Java using `chocolatey` package manager (https://chocolatey.org/) and then reinstall rJava package.

I had a similar issue two weeks ago on a windows laptop.

Comment: WIth the difficulty downloading packages, can I dowload rJava to another computer where download works, then copy the directory from the library of that machine to the one in question?  THe process works for other packages but I am concerned that rJava may have more hookups to the computer's Java.

Comment: what you describe is not really a problem, rJava is something like the peanut butter between two layers of bread (Java and R), sorry if the example is too stupid but it's a way to explain that rJava stays "bounded" and won't affect your system

Comment: Peanut butter sticks to everything and turns rancid.  Java does not touch anything in the computer outside its envelop except what is fed to it or a mouth provided (link or API).  It is continually refreshed.  
Perhaps that is an adequately meated metaphore?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem for a long time. only in RStudio.
Install the package on R and `Library` it. Go to RStudio and `require` the package.

It works!